# How to read the table formated field value in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am displaying all values in table formated

**View:**

```
<div style="clear:both; padding-top:1px;">&nbsp;</div>
<%if @signals[0]!=nil %>
<h1>Signal</h1>
<div class="floatleft width100">
            <div class="floatleft width100 padtop_15">
                <div>
                    <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="300px" border="0" id="mytable">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="title" style="width:20%"><strong>ID</strong></th>
                            <th class="title" style="width:40%"><strong>Signal</strong></th>
                            <th class="title" style="width:20%"><strong>Geo Subnode</strong></th>
                            <th class="title" style="width:20%"><strong>Track Number</strong></th>
                        </tr>
                        <%@signals.each do |signal| %>
                        <tr>
                            <td ><div align="left"><%= signal.ID %></div></td>
                            <td ><div align="left"><%= signal.Name %></div></td>
                            <td ><div align="left"><%= signal.Subnode %></div></td>
                            <td ><div align="left"><%= text_field_tag "sigtrack#{@sigtrk}", "#{signal.Tracknumber}", :size =>"30px",:class=>"inputbox_big2" %></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <% @sigtrk=@sigtrk+1 %>
                        <%end%> 
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>  
<%end%>
```

**Controller:**

@signals--> I am loading the table values(id,signal,subnode,tracknumber) for displaying all details

**Issue:**
User should be able to change the value and need to save those value with database.... here the issue is how to read the table formated field values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want users to be able to change fields in order to store them in the database you need [forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html). [Part 2 of the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects) shows how to create a form for a model, use this information and your loop to create a form for each signal you have.

A more advanced way of changing values is to use AJAX calls, you could made editable table fields. [This page](http://talkingcode.co.uk/2007/12/10/editable-table-with-javascript-tablekit-ajax-and-rails/) shows a demonstation of this method, it is a bit out-dated, but it shows the possibilities. A lot of AJAX/Rails related information canbe found on SO as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, usually this is what forms are for. Usually you would make a _signal.html.erb partial.

In your partial might then have a form fo each of the fields you care about.

There are plenty of examples of how to do forms online. [Here are some great video tutorials with source code on Github](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=forms)